Not enough gap between the rear fender and rack eyelets
I have been running Tubus racks on my Strael 3.0 bike. Recently I bought fenders for the bike but when trying to install I find there isn't enough space for the screw to go into the fender eyelet if I have my rack on. Any ideas on how to resolve it?
Seems like I would have to use the same eyelet for both rack and fenders with longer screws.


Sounds right - many bikes have two eyelets at the back but yours has one.
Fitting fenders/carriers/racks is always an exercise in creativity.
Perhaps trimming a little with a hand-file will give you the clearances you need.
A longer bolt is a practical idea, though make sure its the same or higher grade steel than the old one.  Also, put the heavier-loaded part closer to the frame else lever load might damage things.

Another potential solution is to mount the fender bolts from the inside-out, which puts the fender's stays closer to the wheel and leaves the rack's stays as they are.   Downside of this is access to the bolt heads is through the wheel and between the spokes, needing a long driver or remove the wheel to fit.  Clearance from the bolt-head to the chain might be an issue.
Finally, there exists a small connector called a P-clip, and is generally made of steel or plastic.   You might choose to wrap an appropriately-sized pclip around the rack's stays and then bolt the fender's stays to that.
If you have the tools, you could even drill a hole in each of the rack's flat bits, and then tap that for an M5 bolt.  A small hole won't make a significant difference to its overall strength, especially when there's a bolt in the hole.   Advantage of this is that you can put the hole whereever the stay lands to give the best tyre/guard spacing.

Thanks! Mine does have two eyelets - it’s just that the rack stays are covering up the second eyelets slightly making it impossible to use them.
The trimming idea is an interesting one that I didn’t think of. Do you think it will impact the integrity of the rack too much? Also thanks for the tip on the lever load; I will put the rack first in that case if i go with a single long bolt.
